# InfoPath Image cannot sent by mail SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, image

I have a problem with image in InfoPath form in SharePoint 2013.

I have a InfoPath form which has a Office logo. I need this logo changes to Office name. For example, if Office name is France, it displays french office logo. If Office name is USA, it displays american office logo.

I add a image field **logo** and add a rule to change it. I set logo value is equal to a image link (SharePoint link). I also add rule to send this form in InfoPath. When user submits this form, this form will be sent to approver by mail. But the logo image cannot display in the mail. There is a red cross error.

How can I change logo image and send it to approver ? 
[image]

How can I change logo image and send it to approver ?

Answer (score 0):

I add a section and then insert an image to this section. And add a rule "hide" to this section. It works well.